# How can I declare a variable inside a function thats used more than once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting to use functions for my first time and the issue I am having is declaring a variable inside a function that is used more than once. I got this program working before my attempt to add functions, so the only thing incorrect (im assuming) is my attempt to use functions.

```
print ("Welcome to August's binary arithemetic caclulator.")
firstvalue = input("What is the first binary value?")
secondvalue = input("What is the second binary value?")
operation = input("What operation would you like to carry out? + or - or * or ^")

def bintoint():
    prod, ans, power = 0, 0, 0
    for i in range (-1,-len(firstvalue) - 1,-1):
        try:
            prod = ((int(firstvalue[i])) * ((2**power)))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        ans += prod
        prod = 0
        power += 1
    global ans

firstvalueans = ans

bintoint()
bintoint(firstvalue="secondvalue")

secondvalueans = ans

#prod, ans, power = 0, 0, 0
#for i in range (-1,-len(secondvalue) - 1,-1):
#    try:
#        prod = ((int(secondvalue[i])) * ((2**power)))
#    except ValueError:
#        continue
#    ans += prod
#    prod = 0
#    power += 1
# global secondvalueans
# secondvalueans = ans

if operation == "+":
    totalans = (firstvalueans + secondvalueans)
if operation == ("-"):
    totalans = (firstvalueans - secondvalueans)
if operation == ("*"):
    totalans = (firstvalueans * secondvalueans)
if operation == ("^"):
    totalans = (firstvalueans ** secondvalueans)
try:
    totalans = int(totalans)
except NameError:
    print ("Please enter a valid operator.")
    import sys
    sys.exit()

invertedbinary = []
while totalans >= 1:
    totalans = (totalans/2)
    invertedbinary.append(totalans)
    totalans = int(totalans)
for n,i in enumerate(invertedbinary):
    if (round(i) == i):
        invertedbinary[n]=0
    else:
        invertedbinary[n]=1
if (firstvalue[0] == "-") ^ (secondvalue[0] == "-"):
    invertedbinary.append("-")

invertedbinary.reverse()
result = ''.join(str(e) for e in invertedbinary)
print ( firstvalue , operation , secondvalue , "=" ,result)
```

Note the only declared function, and the block of commented code. The code is identical with the exception of a single variable. So I am trying to execute the function twice, by changing the only difference the variable. The variable I would like to change can be seen as `firstvalue` in `def bintoint()`. For the second time the function is called, I would like `firstvalue` to be replaced with `secondvalue, just like the commented code.

The idea of this script is to take two binary values, convert them into integers, carry out the respective operation between the two integers, convert back into binary and `print ( firstvalue , operation , secondvalue , "=" ,result)`.

So lets say I input the two values in this order:

`100`

`011`

`*`

Expected Output:

`100 * 011 = 1100`

Actual Output:

`TypeError: bintoint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firstvalue'`

So I understand it is something wrong with my attempt at changing the variable within the function. `bintoint(firstvalue="secondvalue")` I also tried without quotation marks but still gave me the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please pare this down to a *minimal* example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Usually it's easier to answer if you try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, there's a lot of unnecessary noise in your question.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read just a little bit farther in your tutorials and learn about function parameters.

Comment: Check out partial functions...https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Comment: what you do there `bintoint(firstvalue="secondvalue")` is not possible since your definition doesnt take any arguments. Change your definition to `def bintoint(value)` and then pass any values you want. No need for the assignment sign (`=`). Just like this: `bintoint(secondvalue)`

Comment: You don't need to declare variables in Python. Just create them as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two important aspects of using functions are passing in arguments and returning the results. If you pass in an argument, then the function will receive a potentially different value each time it is called. If you return the result, then the calling code will receive a different answer each time it calls your function.

Try something like this:

```
def bintoint(value):
    prod, ans, power = 0, 0, 0
    for i in range (-1,-len(value) - 1,-1):
        try:
            prod = ((int(value[i])) * ((2**power)))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        ans += prod
        prod = 0
        power += 1
    return ans
```

Then, in your main code:

```
firstvalueans = bintoint(firstvalue)
secondvalueans = bintoint(secondvalue)
```

More information about functions can be found in [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), in the [*Defining Functions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) section.

*Aside*: In your example, it may be easier to use the [two-argument form of the `int()` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), like so:

```
firstvalueans=int(firstvalue, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Everything is working as expected now. I can use this for all the functions I need now, thanks!

Comment: @AugustWilliams - I found The Python Tutorial immensely helpful when I learned Python. I recommend that you read and work through the entire tutorial before starting your first project. Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I've been doing a bit of everything really on the aspect of learning. Once again, thanks for your help and concern!